# Why using a dot (.) separator in folder structure in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, directory

I'm new to c# & .NET development and I was wondering what is the use of the . in folder structure.

Example:

Folder -> Project.Api

Folder -> Project.Api.Tests

Folder -> Project.Database.Models

I think I'm probably missing something here, so thank you for any explanations on this!

Comment: It is typically representative of the top-level namespacing of each class in those respective projects.  So for instance, if you have a `Home` controller in a Controllers folder in your api project, the namespace for that controller would typically be `Project.Api.Controllers`.

Comment: Most of the time you will find that it aligns with the namespaces in the files that live inside those projects. It's a code organization pattern commonly found in C# solutions.

Comment: That doesn't look like a folder reference at all. However a drill down into a class and it methods is how and what such notation suggests. You can't and don't reference folders as above, but use standard windows file paths. But often to save typing to user's such as in this post then again such notation can be used. But if you not talking about a class and drilling down its methods and property's? Then such notation is just that - some notes as to how the folders are laid out. But to use such folders in code then you using correct file path names - and such notation is only for communication